# Python Image Library Image Resolution when Resizing

Tags: python, image-processing, jpeg, python-imaging-library, resolution

I am trying to shrink some jpeg images from 24X36 inches to 11X16.5 inches using the python image library. Since PIL deals in pixels this should mean scaling from 7200X 4800 pixels to 3300 X2200 pixels, with my resolution set at 200 pixels/inch, however when I run my script PIL changes the resolution to 72 pixels/inch and I end up with a larger image than i had before.

```
import Image

im = Image.open("image.jpg")

if im.size == (7200, 4800):
    out = im.resize((3300,2200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
elif im.size == (4800,7200):
    out = im.resize((2200,3300), Image.ANTIALIAS)

out.show()
```

Is there a way to mantain my image resolution when I'm resizing my images?

thanks for any help!

Comment: you might want to try the thumbnail function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To preserve the DPI, you need to specify it when saving; the `info` attribute is not always preserved across image manipulations:

```
dpi = im.info['dpi']  # Warning, throws KeyError if no DPI was set to begin with

# resize, etc.

out.save("out.jpg", dpi=dpi)
```

Comment: Some image file formats, like .jgp, don't have a dpi value, so I doubt the above would have any effect (and the first line will also result in a `keyerror`).

Comment: @martineau: The OP used a `jpg` file in the example code, and the dpi info doesn't make much sense for many other formats.

Comment: @user1492267: Since I expect the `im.info['dpi']` gave you a `KeyError`, how exactly did this work?

Comment: @martineau: the OP output lost the DPI value; the input has it still. Why expect a KeyError?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm simply trying to understand what they were able to preserve when the input image has no `dpi`, because when I try something like `out.save("out.jpg", dpi=200)` I get a `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: To be clear, whenever I try to do a `dpi = im.info['dpi']` on an image read from a .jpg file, I get a `KeyError`.

Comment: @martineau The program that created my jpeg specifies a dpi when it creates the file. That could explain it, but i don't really know.

Comment: @user1492267 (& Martijn): I see from further reading that the JPEG file format has evolved and nowadays is able to optionally contain horizontal and vertical dpi meta-data -- so the application used to create your images is apparently putting it into your files. Please excuse my misstatements in that regard. To add dpi info to an image read in that doesn't have it, it can be set explicitly using something like `out.save(fout_name, dpi=(200, 200))` -- note that it's actually a pair of values, separate ones for horizontal and vertical.